# Fragment keeps on adding when the button is clicked

Tags: android, fragment

```
ImageButton imageButton3 =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.item_two_timer_id);

imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container2_main , new TimerFragment2())
                              .addToBackStack(null)
                              .commit();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you able to explain what is your real problem.

Comment: You mean to say that when you press imageButton all time your fragment added to container right?

Comment: Yes,  You are right..

Answer (score 1):

While adding fragment add a tag to identify it.get the fragment by tag and see if the fragment is present.If it is not present create a new Instance and add it.

```
ImageButton imageButton3 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.item_two_timer_id);

imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TimerFragment2 timerFragment2;
        timerFragment2 = (TimerFragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TimerFragment2.class.getSimpleName());
        if(timerFragment2==null){
            timerFragment2=new TimerFragment2();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container2_main,  timerFragment2,TimerFragment2.class.getSimpleName())
                        .addToBackStack(TimerFragment2.class.getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
        }else {
            //Dont create fragment again
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Your welcome.please upvote and accept this answer.It helps me a lott :)

Answer (score 0):

please try this code if you are setting one fragment

```
private void initFragment() {
    SelectTypeFragment fragment = new SelectTypeFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right); //if you want to set animation
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_addvehicle, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

if you are replacing one fragment to with another.

```
 void goToNextFragment() {
    ((CreateOfferActivity) this.getActivity()).setCreateOfferModel(createOfferModel);
    SelectVehicleFragment fragment = new SelectVehicleFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_create_offer, fragment).
            addToBackStack("select_vehicle");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: I will execute and see.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in Fragment but first,

You need to create an object of Fragment **TimerFragment2**  and check if it's visible or not in **timerFragment.isVisible()**

```
    ImageButton imageButton3 =(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.item_two_timer_id);
TimerFragment2 timerFragment = new TimerFragment2();

imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!timerFragment.isVisible())
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container2_main , timerFragment)
                              .addToBackStack(null)
                              .commit();
```